# BMesh: Accessing edges of created mesh

Tags: python, scripting, bmesh

Let’s say I created a bunch of these cones in my_bmesh object:

```
c = bmesh.ops.create_cone(my_bmesh, segments=8, diameter1=1, diameter2=1, cap_ends=True)
```

Is there a way to access a cone’s edges (preferably right after I create it) so I could connect it with other cones using bridge edge loops?

Comment: As Develepper myself, dynamically created object generate a random name. if you want to access them in code, you will need to use a specific sequenceand name it with that sequence. like c.Name ='my_bmesh' + [int value used as increment and stored somewhere like global variable]

Comment: I don't need to name the objects; i want to connect two subsequently created cones. The problem is, bmesh.ops.create_cone() returns only a dict of vertices (AFAIK).

Comment: Each vertex of bmesh has its corresponding edges.

Comment: And how can I get these edges?

Comment: Maybe... read the doc a bit and enhance your question when you've tried something. See https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_cone and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVert.link_edges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Slice based on pre op lengths**

It is my experience that new geometry is always appended after using the bmesh create operators.

Hence can look at the length of `bm.faces` before, and use to slice after.

A more robust result could be achieved with sets of elements prior and after.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

nv, ne, nf = (len(bm.verts), len(bm.edges), len(bm.faces))
ret = bmesh.ops.create_cone(bm, 
        segments=3, 
        diameter2=2,
        depth=1,
        cap_ends=True)

print(len(bm.verts[nv:]), "New Verts:", [g.index for g in bm.verts[nv:]])
# check if new verts slice and op return are the same
same_verts = not bool(set(bm.verts[nv:]) - set(ret['verts']))
print("Slice and op return same verts?", same_verts)
print(len(bm.edges[ne:]), "New Edges:", [g.index for g in bm.edges[ne:]])
print(len(bm.faces[nf:]), "New faces:", [g.index for g in bm.faces[nf:]])

''' Result

4 New Verts: [8, 9, 10, 11]
Slice and op return same verts? True
6 New Edges: [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
4 New faces: [6, 7, 8, 9]

'''
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it:

```
(prev_edges -> edges from previous cone)
c = bmesh.ops.create_cone(my_bmesh)
verts = list(c.values())[0]
curr_edges = verts[0].link_faces[0].edges
total_edges = [e for e in prev_edges] + [e for e in curr_edges]
bmesh.ops.bridge_loops(my_bmesh, edges=total_edges)
prev_edges = verts[-1].link_faces[0].edges
```